# Null file object for optional file argument

Tags: python, python-3.x, null, file-handling, mypy

Does the Python Standard Library have a standard tool to create a null file object? By this I mean a file object which would not be related to an existing file. It should also behave as a closed file (reading or writing would fail).

**Reasoning for the need:** I use functions which take opened file as an argument but in certain parameter combinations the file is not being used. Instead of using `None` value and polluting the code with `typing.Optional[]` and `assert` (or even additional `if` as I think Mypy does not even understand `assert`!):

```py
def function(arguments: argparse.Namespace, file: typing.Optional[typing.TextIO]) -> None:
    if not arguments.do_not_use_file:
        assert file is not None
        do_something(file)
```

I would like to use the null file object.

The best way how to create the null file object I was able to find is:

```py
import io

NULL_FILE = io.StringIO()
NULL_FILE.close()
```

With the null file object the code would be:

```py
def function(arguments: argparse.Namespace, file: typing.TextIO) -> None:
    if not arguments.do_not_use_file:
        do_something(file)
```

Is there a better way to create the null file object or handle optional file parameters?

Comment: Is there a reason why you actually want a *closed* file object? Would a well-defined file object such as `/dev/null` also match your purpose? The "better" way is likely not to be in this situation at all – functions working on files ("doing I/O") are usually something else than functions working just by themselves. In other words, ``function`` should not be called in the first place if ``arguments.do_not_use_file`` is false.

Comment: Would overloading your method/function make sense?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi There are two main reasons why I want a file object not tied to real filesystem entity: 1. security - attempt to use the closed file throws an exception - that is exactly what I want 2. removing unnecessary dependencies and actions (e.g. existence of /dev/null - I guess it would fail e.g. on Windows). --- Separating I/O and processing: I do not think it is really suitable in this case - processing of files with hundreds of thousands lines. Maybe it could be done using generators and coroutines but I do not know coroutines enough yet and I feel over-complication hiding there.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf Python does not support function overloading or am I missing something? Anyway the function contains the processing code interleaved with I/O operations - overloading the function would need duplication of all the processing code.